# Base point of a line that intersects an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Given is an ellipse in the plane with half-axes a and b and a straight line $g$ (see image below). The line $g$ is of the form

\begin{align*}
g(t)=\{x+tv: t \in \mathbb{R}\}.
\end{align*},

where $x$ is the (first) intersection of the line with the ellipse.

[image]

I want to describe the line alternatively by choosing another base point, i. instead of $ x $ a new base point $ x ^ * $ should be chosen. 
A typical choice would be e.g. to take the closest point to the origin $ 0 $. Then you can describe $ x ^ * $ by

\begin{align*}
x^*=x-\langle x,v \rangle v,
\end{align*}

with the standard scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. My question ist now: How can i describe the "old" base point $x$ in terms of the new point $x^*$? It is clear, that $x=x^*+\langle x,v \rangle v$, but here i have still $x$ at the right side of the formula. I am hoping to find something like $x=x(x^*,v)$ or maybe depending on the half axes $a$ and $b$. Is this possible in a compact form?

Comment: If you think of it you'll realise that finding $x$ without some more info is impossible. Besides: what has the ellipse to do with your question?

Comment: i forgot to mention that $x$ is the (first) intersection of the line with the ellipse, like you see in the image. So should it not be possible to describe $x$ in terms of $a$, $b$ and $x^*$, $v$?

Comment: It's possible if you know the equation of the ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.

The equation of the ellipse can be written as $X^TAX=1$, where 
$A=\pmatrix{1/a^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/b^2\\}$.

Substitute there $X=x^*+vt$ and solve for $t$, retaining only the negative solution.